# How to sort a list with strings and integers?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, numbers

I have some code:

```
def params_to_list(x, y, z):
    """(object, object, object) -> list

    Return a list containing x, y and z, in order.
    >>> params_to_list('hello', "month", 3)
    ['hello', 'month', 3]
    """
```

I need to create a function. I've tried using the `sorted` method but it returns an error:

> builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) states that sorting between different types is implementation-defined:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but **arbitrarily**

The most consistent way here seems to sort *as if* everything was a string:

```
def params_to_list(*params):
    return sorted(params, key=lambda p: str(p))
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how exactly you want your arguments to be sorted, but you can just call the built-in function `sorted()`

```
def params_to_list(*params):
    return sorted(list(params))
```

Comment: You don't need the `list(`: `return sorted(params)` does the same.